# Prevent IP address conflicts on a heterogeneous network consisting of PCs and embedded systems in a retail environment

Tags: networking, ip-address, embedded

In our LAN environment (wired and wireless), IP Address conflict almost always gets our systems down.

We have a lot of equipment connected to the network: PC's, Access Points, RF, weighing scales, POS machines.  Each equipment has its own range of defined IP Addresses.  However, IP's are statically assigned.  External vendors configure their respective equipment offline.  This is almost often the case of conflict when the machines are connected to the network.

We already know how to troubleshoot and resolve the conflict.  What I want to ask now is HOW TO BLOCK OR PREVENT INTRODUCTION OR CONNECTION of any machine/equipment to our network with IP address that is in conflict with the existing and used IPs?

I'm planning to run LookAtLan on a scheduled task say 2am daily so we could get a fresh list of all IP and Mac addresses used, then create a program that will automatically execute validation (of IP) upon detection of any new entry to the network via the switch ports (for wired only - I have nothing for wireless).

Once new entry has been validated in conflict with existing, WHAT AND HOW TO PREVENT ENTRY is my MAIN PROBLEM.

I don't know if my plans are feasible and possible.  Please help.

Comment: Look into DHCP and perhaps MAC address reservations for the critical data network. Have a separate guest subnet for the ad hoc connections to ensure conflicts there are only with guest devices and perhaps set it up with DHCP as well.

Comment: Unfortunately, enterprise hardware or software questions are off-topic here—please try [sf] instead. See the [help/on-topic] for details. (Please don't cross-post—if you post your question there, you should delete the question here.)

Comment: Any host with a statically assigned address will use that address, and if it conflicts with an existing assigned address, you get a conflict. That's really all there is to it. You need to use DHCP, instead of statically assigned addresses, to prevent such problems.

Comment: @1Fish_2Fish_RedFish_BlueFish: Thank you for the immediate response.  However, we don't use DHCP because of bandwidth synchronization issues with the central office.  guest subnet is not feasible since new entries will be permanently part of the network.

Comment: This is going to be a very tricky question to answer. Your network consists of a lot of different embedded systems each with their own IP configuration. If it's possible to configure the POS/scales/etc. to use DHCP, do so; otherwise, see if you can change the IP addresses of the devices in question.

Comment: @Katt, without knowing your network its tough to say for sure, but it sounds like you could run your own DHCP server on your network (separate from your central office) which would manage the subnets/IPs you're responsible.  Also, it sounds like you really need to do some break your network into subnets to isolate your every day devices from the transient ones.

Comment: `IP Address conflict almost always gets our systems down` - what exactly does it mean? I mean there should be a way how to maintain the rest of the system's functionality even with some ocassional IP address conflict. What network hardware (switches) do you use?

Comment: Interesting Q&A for you here http://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/a/2949

Answer (score 0):

As it seems you are using IPv4, the network conflicts of static IP address can be found by [Gratuitous ARP](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/a/7716). The problem is, that this detection works only **after the conflict happens**.

You can though minimalize the impact of the IP address conflict using security features of some switches, like [Cisco's Dynamic ARP Inspection](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/switches/lan/catalyst6500/ios/12-2SX/configuration/guide/book/dynarp.html) as suggested [in this answer](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/a/2949).

> DAI is a security feature that validates ARP packets in a network.
> DAI intercepts, logs, and discards ARP packets with invalid IP-to-MAC
> address bindings. This capability protects the network from some
> man-in-the-middle attacks.

So basically **in IPv4 you cannot prevent static (non-DHCP assigned) IP address conflict and you have to concentrate on minimizing the impact of eventual conflict on your system**, which can be achieved by using proper network hardware and configuration.

If you used IPv6, you would benefit from [Optimistic Duplicate Address Detection (DAD) for IPv6](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4429).

> With IPv4 gratuitous ARP, the Source Protocol Address and Target
> Protocol Address fields in the ARP Request message header are set to
> the IPv4 address for which duplication is being detected. In IPv6 DAD,
> the Target Address field in the Neighbor Solicitation (NS) message is
> set to the IPv6 address for which duplication is being detected. DAD
> differs from address resolution in the following ways:
>
> - In the DAD NS message, the Source Address field in the IPv6 header is set to the unspecified address (::). T**he address being queried for
>   duplication cannot be used until it is determined that there are no
>   duplicates.**
> - In the Neighbor Advertisement (NA) reply to a DAD NS message, the Destination Address in the IPv6 header is set to the link-local
>   all-nodes multicast address (FF02::1). The Solicited flag in the NA
>   message is set to 0. Because the sender of the DAD NS message is not
>   using the desired IP address, it cannot receive unicast NA messages.
>   Therefore, the NA message is multicast.
> - Upon receipt of the multicast NA message with the Target Address field set to the IP address for which duplication is being detected,
>   **the node disables the use of the duplicate IP address on the
>   interface**. If the node does not receive an NA message that defends the
>   use of the address, it initializes the address on the interface.

So in IPv6 the conflict is detected before it happens and the duplicate IP address cannot be used until it is determined that there are no duplicates.